# Components communication in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Probably is simple but i'm going crazy.
The first component is the parent

```ts
export class CompaniesComponent {
  companies: Company[];
  companiesShown: Company[];
}
constructor(private _companiesService: CompaniesService) {
    this._companiesService.getCompanies().subscribe(data => {
        this.companies = JSON.parse( data.text() );
        this.companiesShowed = this.companies;
    });
}
```

The template is like this:

```ts
..
<tr *ngFor="let company of companiesShowed">
    <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
</tr>
..
<app-pagination [data]="companies" [(dataShown)]="companiesShown"></app-pagination>
```

Finally, the children is like this:

```ts
export class PaginationComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() data: Object[];
  @Input() dataShown: Object[];
  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.data != null && this.data.length > 0 ) {
        this.dataShown = this.data;
        console.log(this.dataShown);
    }
 }
}
```

Console.log give me the right length of dataShown, but in the parent is alway undefined / zero length... why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "two-way binding" like

```ts
[(dataShown)]="companiesShown"
```

to work, your child component needs

```ts
@Input() dataShown: Object[];
@Output() dataShownChange: EventEmitter<Object[]> = new EventEmitter<Object[]>();
```

where updates from child to parent are sent like

```ts
this.dataShownChange.emit([{x: 'y'}]);
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way

Comment: Ok, but i can't emit in an ngOnChanges() method without get an error like "Expression has changed after it was checked."

Comment: So you want to emit `dataShownChange` when `data` changed? What's the exact error message?

Comment: I simplified the code, but the list of companies comes from an http request, so when the app-pagination is built companies is null.
I subscribe the http request and next i map json into an array (companies).
When the array is filled the component app-pagination have to slice the array companies and put it in companiesShown, i intercept this event (companies is not empty) by the method NgOnChanges, but this method can't notify the parent. So i don't know what i have to do :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment or how this is related to the problem. What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: error_handler.js:50 EXCEPTION: Error in ./CompaniesComponent class CompaniesComponent - inline template:11:16 caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'.

Comment: you can inject `privat cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef` and call `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` after `....emit(...)`. This should make the exception go away

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work.